# Endpoint conflict

Tags: node.js, typescript, loopbackjs, loopback4

Whenever I execute the following endpoint I get an ID type error.

```
Request GET /lists/45 failed with status code 500. error: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "45"
```

The problematic endpoint:

```
//  @get('/blabla/{color}', {   //---> Works!
  @get('/lists/{color}', {   //---> Error!
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Query all lists by color',
      },
    },
  })
  async getListByColor(@param.path.string('color') color: number): Promise<number> {
    return this.listsRepository.dataSource.execute("SELECT * FROM public.lists as li WHERE li.color = " + color);
  }
```

The other endpoint works fine:

```
  @get('/lists/{id}', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Lists model instance',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: getModelSchemaRef(Lists, {includeRelations: true}),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  async findById(
    @param.path.string('id') id: string,
    @param.filter(Lists, {exclude: 'where'}) filter?: FilterExcludingWhere<Lists>
  ): Promise<Lists> {
    return this.listsRepository.findById(id, filter);
  }
```

Comment: For future reference, this question has been posted elsewhere: https://loopbackio.slack.com/archives/C01177XQN8N/p1607170208092200 . If this question hasn't been answered here yet, please check the link above. | See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5048 on how to join the Slack channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 endpoints, `/lists/{color}` and `/lists/{id}` are indistinguishable for the REST Router as both paths would resolve to `/lists/{an arbitrary string}`.
Hence, the Router may be routing the traffic to the wrong endpoint that requires a UUID-datatype id. Hence, the database engine-level error.

Please also be aware that the first example is susceptible to an SQL injection attack. Please consider using [Parameterized SQL](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.repository.defaultcrudrepository.execute.html) instead.